# Add-on Manager checkboxes select more than one

Tags: add-on, ee3

Is this a feature or a bug?

I have a fresh install of EE 3.5.15 (and have noticed this on other installs, thus my test on the fresh version).  If I'm in the CMS on a page with checkboxes, such as the add-on manager.  I click one checkbox in the middle of the row and several above it are also activated.  It's not all above and it's not the same # of boxes above each time.  And after you uncheck everything you are then able to check just a single box if it happened to be included in the initial auto selection.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens here. Every list with checkboxes, like the list of a field set.
Meanwhile I am used to press CTRL and then click the checkbox. That only checks that checkbox.
I have no idea why this happens.